# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm writing a cron job in that will run every minute to send Firebase notifications to users under a condition (if time stored in database is less than current time in development. In production, if stored time is equal to current time). In cron job's handle function, I have the following code

```
public function handle()
{
    // get current time
    $current_time = Carbon::now()->format('H:i:00');
    // get all daily_checks's user_id where time matches current time
    $matched_check_user_id = DailyCheck::where('time', '<', $current_time)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
    \Log::debug($matched_check_user_id);
    \Log::debug(gettype($matched_check_user_id));
    // get fcm_tokens of matched user_ids
    $fcm_tokens = Device::whereIn('user_id', '=', $matched_check_user_id)->pluck('fcm_token')->toArray();
    // send firebase notifications
    \Log::debug($fcm_tokens);
}
```

Please take two tables under consideration. **daily_checks** table where I'm comparing the time to send the notification and the **devices** table where I have the **fcm_token** stored. Both have user_id as foreign key.

First, I get all user id's from **daily_checks** where my time condition is met.

```
$matched_check_user_id = DailyCheck::where('time', '<', $current_time)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
```

Then, I try to get Fcm_tokens of matched user_ids where I encounter the error

```
$fcm_tokens = Device::whereIn('user_id', '=', $matched_check_user_id)->pluck('fcm_token')->toArray();
```

I have logged all the results. Here is the screenshot of log file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue here:

```
$fcm_tokens = Device::whereIn('user_id', '=', $matched_check_user_id)->pluck('fcm_token')->toArray();
```

you have to pass an array in to whereIn;

```
$fcm_tokens = Device::whereIn('user_id',[])->pluck('fcm_token')->toArray();
```

or pas it as where:

```
 $fcm_tokens = Device::where('user_id', $matched_check_user_id)->pluck('fcm_token')->toArray();
```

Comment: When I have log debugged it here. 
\Log::debug($matched_check_user_id);
\Log::debug(gettype($matched_check_user_id));
It prints an array and type is also array in the image. 
When I did
$matched_check_user_id = DailyCheck::where('time', '<', $current_time)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
The user_id's came in the array

Comment: But, when I used it with 'where' it ran but it only gave me one result associated with id 6. But, right scenario would be when it gets fcm_token for id 2 and 3 as well.

Comment: What happen if use   Device::whereIn('user_id',$matched_check_user_id)